# How can Java ArrayList change value while passing as argument?

Tags: java

Good Day.

I am pretty sure that this question has been asked before but I couldn't find it.

Basically, how does the below code work:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        a.add(10);
        
        change(a);
        
        System.out.println(a.get(0));
    }
    
    static void change(ArrayList v){
        if(v.size() > 0){
            v.set(0, "Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles and also runs successfully, printing "Hello". How could Java replace Integer with String?

I also tried adding in Main:

```
        a.set(0, 1002);
        
        for(Integer c: a){
            System.out.print(c + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
```

Once again, very surprising. I thought that maybe somwhow `a` gets changed to `ArrayList<String>` but the `set` method works normally?

Can anyone please explain this to me? Is this undefined behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: You could do it you you used `Object` as your list type `(e.g. new ArrayList<Object>`  But lists of mixed types is not not a good idea and can lead to problems.

Comment: When you compiled this code, you would have got a warning.  That warning was telling you this could happen.

Comment: Java doesn't replace Integer with String. `System.out.println(a.get(0));`Is using [println(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)) So it doesn't need to cast the String to an Integer. If you tired `Integer b = v.get(0);` you'd get different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic types like the `<Integer>` in your `ArrayList` are a compile-time concept, this information is lost at runtime. This is known as "type erasure".

You just use `ArrayList` (without type parameter) in the `change` method, which means that the compiler will not check for a type, so it's possible to add a String to an Integer List. If you used `ArrayList<Integer>`, the compiler would complain.

Internally, `ArrayList` uses a simple array of objects that can hold any type.